# Trying to convert text into hex by calling a function within my batch file, but the hex code never gets returned to the Main batch function

Tags: batch-file, return-value

```
@echo off

goto :main

 
:strg2hex
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Store the string in chr.tmp file
set /P "=%~1" < NUL > chr.tmp

rem Create zero.tmp file with the same number of Ascii zero characters
for %%a in (chr.tmp) do fsutil file createnew zero.tmp %%~Za > NUL

rem Compare both files with FC /B and get the differences
set "hex="
for /F "skip=1 tokens=2" %%a in ('fc /B chr.tmp zero.tmp') do set "hex=!hex!%%a"

del chr.tmp zero.tmp
echo The string to hex is %hex%

set %~1=%hex%

goto :eof



:main

     echo This is the main function!
 
     ::This interprets "tiger" as a string.
     ::This will convert text "tiger" into hex with the above function.
     call :strg2hex tiger
     Echo this is text "tiger" converted into hex: %hex%

Pause

goto :eof
```

Comment: You seem not to be aware what the line `set %~1=%hex%` is intended to: it's used to assign the result to a variable whose name is provided to the sub-routine as first argument. Besides the `endlocal` issue described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72120744), you actually supply a text string argument to the function rather than a variable name. So simply replacing that line by `endlocal & set "hex=%hex%"` is all you'll need. *N. B.:* I've got a suggestion for a easier text-to-hex conversion for you, namely [`certutil -encodehex`](https://ss64.com/nt/certutil.html#encodehex)…

Comment: Thanks, @aschipfl.  Will check out your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in place of

```
set %~1=%hex%
```

use

```
endlocal&set "%~1=%hex%"&SET "hex=%hex%"
```

Because you are executing a `setlocal`, when you `goto :eof`, the local environment containing your changes is deleted and the original, unchanged environment is restored.

This statement works because batch parses, substitutes and then executes the command, so what is actually executed is

```
 endlocal&set "tiger=7469676572"&SET "hex=7469676572"
```

so the local environment is deleted, then the values are `set`.

---

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
goto :main

 
:strg2hex
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Store the string in chr.tmp file
set /P "=%~1" < NUL > chr.tmp

rem Create zero.tmp file with the same number of Ascii zero characters
for %%a in (chr.tmp) do DEL zero.tmp>nul&fsutil file createnew zero.tmp %%~Za > NUL

rem Compare both files with FC /B and get the differences
set "hex="
for /F "skip=1 tokens=2" %%a in ('fc /B chr.tmp zero.tmp') do set "hex=!hex!%%a"

rem del chr.tmp zero.tmp
echo The string to hex is %hex%

endlocal&SET "hex=%hex%"


goto :eof

:main
u:
     echo This is the main function!
 
     ::This interprets "tiger" as a string.
     ::This will convert text "tiger" into hex with the above function.
     call :strg2hex tiger
     Echo this is text "tiger" converted into hex: %hex%


IF "%*" neq "" FOR %%z IN (%*) DO  ECHO %%z&     call :strg2hex %%z

rem response to comment

SET "strng=Lion"
CALL :strg2hex %strng%
ECHO This variable "strng" has been converted into %hex%
ECHO This variable "strng" value "%strng%" has been converted into %hex%

GOTO :EOF
```

Well - a couple of surprises on testing more thoroughly...

First, I use `U:` for testing - that's why that has appeared at the start of `main`.

Next, I've added a new line,

```
IF "%*" neq "" FOR %%z IN (%*) DO  ECHO %%z&     call :strg2hex %%z
```

This looks at the command-line "tail" (the data after the program name on the command line) or *parameters* `%*` and assigns each one in turn to `%%z` (parameters may be space-separated or comma-separated), then `echo`es the parameter and `call`s the routine. Thus if we execute

```
q72120539 elephant lion zebra giraffe
```

we get the result

```
elephant
The string to hex is 656C657068616E74
lion
The string to hex is 6C696F6E
zebra
The string to hex is 7A65627261
giraffe
The string to hex is 67697261666665
```

in addition to the `tiger` folderol. `q72120539` is my name for this program.

I had converted the `del`  of the two temporary files to a remark, so the files were not deleted and I could see them...

Unfortunately, the resultant display was not what I expected.

Despite its description (or implications), `fsutil file createnew` does ***NOT*** create a new file if there is an existing file - it leaves it as-is. Consequently, the code did not change the file after the first name (`tiger`) had been processed and the file remained at 5 bytes.

I cured that by deliberately deleting the `zero` file before the `fsutil` command was executed.

So - all fixed now, but I've left the `del` for the temporary files "remmed-out" so that will not be deleted when the routine ends. Probably good practice to remove the `rem`  keyword and  turn the clean-up back on.

I've also removed the `set "%~1=%hex%"` because leaving it would `set` variables named `tiger` , `elephant` , `lion` , `zebra` , `giraffe` each to their hex-value strings.

---

Edited to include example from OP.

Result is extra

```
This variable "strng" has been converted into 4C696F6E
This variable "strng" value "Lion" has been converted into 4C696F6E
```

There is no such thing as a "function" in batch, at least, not in the sense that it is used in Pascal, for instance. The "return value" simply gets assigned to a known variable, as in this case.

It *is* possible to have the `call` return the value in a any variable by using this:

```
call :function fred 5 6 7

...

:function
set /a %1=%2+%3+%4
goto :eof
```

which would set the value of `fred` to `18`

Comment: Hello @Magoo. Would it be possible to pass a variable to the strg2hex function as opposed to a string. For example, instead of string "tiger" it would be variable "%tiger%"  ?

Comment: Yes, BUT you'd need to remove the `set "%~1=%hex%"` as if `tiger` contained `fox` then the `set "%~1=%hex%"` would cause `fox` to be set to the hex value of "fox"

Comment: Hello @Magoo.  I still don't see how I can pass the value of a variable when calling a function, instead of passing the actual string. 
For example:

**strng=Lion
call :strg2hex %strng%
Echo This variable "strng" has been converted into "TheVariableValueReturnedByTheFunction"**

Comment: Thanks @Magoo! I believe that did the trick.